Calculate the integral with the Gauss Green formula
Calculate the following double integral (directly and with the Gauss Green formula)
$$\iint_D xy\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{dy}\\ D=\{(x,y)\in \Bbb R^2|\,\,y\le x \le \sqrt{y+2}, 0\le y \le 2\}$$
directly: $$\int^2_0\int^\sqrt{y+2}_y xy \ \ \mathrm{dx} \ \mathrm{dy}$$$$\int xy \ \mathrm{dx} = y \ \cdot \int x \ \mathrm{dx} = \frac{x^2y}{2} \bigg|_y^{\sqrt{y+2}} = \frac{-y^3+y^2+2y}{2}$$$$\int \frac{-y^3+y^2+2y}{2} \ \mathrm{dy} = \frac{1}{2} \cdot \left(- \frac{y^4}{4}+\frac{y^3}{3}+y^2\right) = \left(- \frac{y^4}{8}+\frac{y^3}{6}+\frac{y^2}{2}\right)\Bigg|_0^2 = \frac{4}{3}$$
Now its required to calculate the double integral using the Gauss Green formula so:
$$\int\int\limits_D {\left( {{{\partial Q} \over {\partial x}} - {{\partial P} \over {\partial y}}} \right)da}  = \int\limits_{\partial D} {Pdx + Qdy}$$
Now think I should choose for example $P = 0$ 
if i do that then
$$\iint_D \frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} \mathrm{da} = \int_{\partial D} Q \ \mathrm{dy}$$
so now I have to find a $Q$ such that
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial x} = xy$$ so 
$$Q=\int xy \ \mathrm{dx} = \frac{x^2y}{2}$$
Now by the green theorem: 
$$\iint_D xy \  \mathrm{da} = \int_{\partial D} \frac{x^2y}{2}$$
I got here and I don't know how to continue. If anyone can help me I would really appreciate it :). 
I attach photos of $D$:


@JeanMarie the domain I had to represent was this: $D$ is the domain contained in the first quadrant and delimited by the $x$ axis, the parabola $y = x^2-2$ and $y=x$. I don't understand where I went wrong, could you show me (if possible) the solution?


Your domain is indeed the "almost triangular" region $OPQ$ that can be seen on the graphical representation above with extreme points :
$$O(0,0), \ P(\sqrt{2},0), \ Q(2,2)$$
$OP$ is a straight line segment, $PQ$ is an arc of parabola, $QO$ is a straight line segment (take care to consider orientation $QO$ and not $OQ$).
Therefore, your integral breaks into 3 parts :
$$\underbrace{\int_{OP} \frac12 x^2y}_0+\underbrace{\int_{PQ} \frac12 x^2y}_{I_1}+\underbrace{\int_{QO} \frac12 x^2y}_{I_2}$$
where
$$I_1=\int_{y=0}^2 \frac12 (y+2)y dy = \frac43 + 2\tag{1}$$
$$I_2=\int_{y=2}^0 \frac12 y^3 dy = -2\tag{2}$$
(please note the order of the bounds in (2))
When you sum up (1) and (2), you retrieve your result $\frac43$.

Now the domain is very clear, but I didn't understand 3 things. $(1.)$ How did you get $(y+2)y$ and $y^3$? $(2.)$ Do we choose $∫^2_{y=0}$ because we integrate by $dy$? Could I choose to integrate by $dx$? If so, should I have used $∫_y^\sqrt{y+2}$? $(3.)$ why did we have to reverse the bounds here $∫^0_{y=2}$? If you can clarify these 3 points for me, you will do me a great favor. Thanks so much again! @JeanMarie


On boundary PQ we have $(y+2)=x^2$, just because we are on the edge between constraints $y+2 \ge x^2$, and $y+2 \le x^2$, ... 2) Yes, in general, you can choose either variable but not under the form you give : it would be numerical values on the bounds : $\int_{x=0}^2 \frac12 x^2 (x^2-2)dx$ 3) To take into account the fact that $OPQO$ is a (positively) orented path giving in particular a backward orientation to line segment $QO$.


ok the points $(2)$ and $(3)$ seem clear enough to me, I just still don't understand how you got it: $\frac12 (y+2)y \ \ \ \text{and}\ \ \ \frac12 y ^3$ Could you show me the steps? Sorry if I'm tagging you all the time. @JeanMarie

Just by replacing in $\frac12 x^2y$ for example $x$ by $\sqrt{y+2}$ (because we are in the case of equality in $y+2 \ge x^2$ giving $\frac12 (\sqrt{y+2})^2y$

clear, last question, but can't I for example replace $\sqrt{y+2}$ in $I_2$ and $y$ in $I_1$? @JeanMarie

No because for example $I_2$ is associated with line segent $QO$ where all points $(x,y)$ are such that $y=x$ but not such that $x=\sqrt{y+2}$...

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
